# How to Collapse a DIV in Blazor without any NuGet Package

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

Is there any possibility to Show / Hide or Collapse / Toggle a div in Blazor without any NuGet package? I have tried many solutions, but it is not satisfied any of my requirements, I need the exact functionality of Bootstrap Collapse in Blazor Razor.

Comment: What have you already tried? can you show us your progress so far? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and edit your  question. The question asked this way will most likely be closed.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need any blazor/c# code for bootstrap collapse to work, it's all done via javascript, see this here: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/4ko895mb

Below code is copied directly from [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#example)

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to use blazor/c#, check this solution where you can use a flag to show/hide a div content:
https://blazorfiddle.com/s/4tr82rnn

```cs
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" @onclick="@(() => { IsVisible = !IsVisible; })">
    Link with href
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse @(IsVisible ? "show" : "")">
  <div class="card card-body">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

@code {
    protected bool IsVisible { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The first fiddle does not work any more, are you able to update it? copypasting the code into my project doe snot work (clicking the button has no effect)

Comment: @M.M the fiddles have been updated.

Comment: OK, thanks. Turned out my problem is that Blazor by default gives projects boostrap.min.css but not bootstrap.min.js   , so [had to install that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1189167/blazor-visual-studio-sample-template-missing-boots)